# Can I pass variables to eval?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to pass a variable to a dynamically declared method like:

```
eval(def test(name)
 puts name
end
test 'joe')
```

but it does not work.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm really, really confused as to what you're trying to do. `eval` is not the tool for this job. How about `define_method`?

Answer (score 11):

`eval` expects a string. The following should work fine:

```
eval "def test(name)
  puts name
end
test 'joe'"
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding Brian. It works. 

Not sure why I missed that.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to declare a method dynamically then a better way to do that is to use `define_method` instead of eval, like so

```
define_method(:test) do |name|
  name
end

test 'joe'
#=> joe
```

Don't use eval unless it is absolutely necessary and you are 120% sure that it is safe. Even if you are 120% sure that it is safe, still try to look for other options and if you find one then use that instead of eval.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused on what you are trying to do.  If you are trying to define a method with eval that can take a parameter here is the example:

```
eval "def test(name)
  puts name
end"

test 'joe'
```

If you want to use eval to define a method that is more dynamic and uses a variable, since as Brian pointed out eval takes a string you would do something like this:

```
test_name = 'joe'
eval "def test
  puts '#{test_name}'
end"

test
```

Comment: Either works, depending on what the OP wants. Clearly he'll be interpolating something somewhere, since, otherwise, why use `eval`?

Comment: I was trying to read a method stored in the database and then execute it with parameters.

Comment: Do you know that the parameters are and their order before you read it in?  If so then using eval with the string should work.